# Question about the definition of an $H$-space

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

> A pointed space $(X, x_0)$ is called an $H$-space if there is a pointed map $m:(X \times X, (x_0, x_0)) \rightarrow (X, x_0)$ such that each of the **(necessarily pointed) maps $m(x_0, )$ and $m(, x_0)$ on $(X, x_0)$** is homotopic to $1_X \text{ rel} \{x_0\}$.

I don't understand anything in the bolded text.  How are the maps $m(x_0, )$ and $m(,x_0)$ defined?  Why are they necessarily pointed?  What does it mean for the maps to be pointed **on** $(X, x_0)$?

I'm self learning this, so as clear an explanation as possible would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $m(x_0,):(X,x_0)\to (X,x_0)$ is the map that sends $x\in X$ to $m(x_0,x)$.  This is automatically a pointed map (that is, it sends $x_0$ to $x_0$) since $m$ is assumed to be a pointed map, so $m(x_0,x_0)=x_0$.  Similarly, $m(,x_0)$ is the map that sends $x\in X$ to $m(x,x_0)$.